# What is this typescript error when using lit context?

Tags: typescript, lit-element, lit

I am using @lit-labs/context v0.3.3 and typescript v4.7.4 with experimentalDecorators support enabled. I have this custom element using lit context:

```
class MyComponent extends LitElement {
  @consume({ context: loggedInContext })
  @property({ attribute: false })
  loggedIn: Boolean = false;
}
```

The context is working as expected, however I am getting the following typescript error just for the `@consume` line:

```
Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
  Argument of type 'MyComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactiveElement'.
    Types have separate declarations of a private property '__instanceProperties'.ts(1240)
```

The other decorators have no such issue. Why am I seeing this error just for the `@consume` decorator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to TypeScript doing nominal typing for classes with private properties. You likely have multiple versions of `@lit/reactive-element` in your project.

Try `npm ls @lit/reactive-element` to see what versions you have installed from what dependencies and `npm dedupe` to get just a single copy.

Version `@lit/reactive-element@1.6.2` and later should no longer have this issue so updating is another solution.